# Any way to show an activity after recovering from process termination?

Tags: android, android-activity, garbage-collection

Is there a way to launch an activity when returning to an application after it was terminated to free up memory?  Android is attempting to start the previous activity, but some data I need has been cleaned up during termination.  If I can push my home activity onto the stack when returning, my app will be able to function properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Use sharedPrefresnces to store data. Whenever the activity starts again, put the data back in order in order to use it.

Comment: Simple hack add android:excludeFromRecents in android manifest for the activity that you are having trouble, so that whenever ur app launches from the recent it will land on the home activity

Comment: I have a bit too much data to offload it to shared preferences- several small collections of objects.  @vikki_logs: This won't work for me since it would prevent the activities from ever being reactivated- not just after termination.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a `public static` variable somewhere, which is set to `true` when your main activity has completed its initialization.

In your other activities, in `onCreate()`, check if this variable is set to `true`. If not, it means that Android has killed and recreated your process and restarted just the top activity. In this case, just launch the main activity using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. This will clear the task stack and start your main activity.

This will only work if the main activity is always in the task stack, at the very bottom (root activity). This means that your main activity should NOT call `finish()` when it launches other activities on top of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

put an EXTRA value into the intent starting the second activity, anything really, just to indicate it was started from your `MainActivity`. Then, in the second Activity's `onCreate()` use `getIntent()` to obtain the intent that started it. If it contains your extra value, do nothing and let the activity start normally. If it does not, `finish()` the second Activity and start `MainActivity`.

Comment: This solution will not work. If the process is terminated and then the user returns to the app, Android will create a new process and will reinstantiate the top Activity, call `onCreate()` on that Activity passing it the **original `Intent` that the Activity was started with, including all of its extras!** This means that the second Activity will always see the extra in `onCreate()`, even if the process has been terminated and recreated.